# How to authenticate many requests made with Lambda using oAuth

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, amazon-sqs

I'm new to AWS, so please tell me when I miss something really obvious.

Basically I have a producer which produces a bunch of messages that need to be POSTed to another server. The POST requests have to be authenticated with oAuth2.

My approach is that I have a Lambda function which runs once a day and sends a bunch of messages into an SQS queue and then another Lambda function which consumes the messages and POSTs them to the server. To do the authentication I was thinking to have the Producer generate a Bearer token once which gets appended to all of the messages so that the consumers can authenticate without any additional API calls.

Now the issue is if there are so many messages in the queue that going through all of them takes more than an hour, at which point the bearer token is expired.

My naive approach would have been to just check in the consumer lambda if the token is expired and if it is to request a new one. However that is really inefficient. So how do I then get a new bearer token (and where do I save it) that all of the remaining messages can use to authenticate, without each lambda having to request their own token.

Comment: What is wrong with each lambda (execution environment) having their own token? Lambda execution environments *can* have state if you are careful about it, e.g. a single lambda execution environment can get a token, store it in some kind of global variable and subsequent invocations in the same environment can use the same token.

Comment: Ah I thought that variables do not persist between invocations. I thought that at that point each invocation of the lambda would have to request a new token, which the token endpoint would definitely not like with so many requests a second. I'll see if I can find some information about persisting variables. However I'm a bit skeptical how it would work with Lambda concurrency

Comment: Okay, I see now. I wasn't aware of the difference between private and global scope in a lambda. Thanks for pointing that out! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/global-scope.html

Comment: Different lambda execution environments / concurrent executions cannot share state but subsequent executions can. If you have a concurrency of 20 each of the 20 execution environments will hit the token endpoint once to get a token. That is obviously more than hitting it only once but still far better than hitting it once per message.